# Showing duplicate links with magic fields wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to Display a download link using two fields in the backend using magic fields (wordpress)

My code to display one link is.

```
<?php if (get('upload_file') != "") { ?>  <p><a href="<?php echo get('upload_file'); ?>">Download - <?php echo get('upload_file_name'); ?></a></p>
            <?php } ?>
```

This works fine and displays it as a link on the front end.

But my magic fields are in groups. So when i duplicate a group the in the back end. and add another name and file etc. It does not show in the front end. it just shows the one.

Can any one show me how to get the links showing in the front? no matter how many times i duplicate the fields?

Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this.

This is the code i used. incase anyone wants to know.

```
<?php $members = get_group('upload'); ?>
                <?php foreach ($members as $member): ?>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo $member['upload_file'] [1] ?>"> Download - <?php echo $member['upload_file_name'] [1] ?></a></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```